# Permissions on a messed up OS X hard drive

Tags: mount, permissions, hard-drive

I'm trying to help a mate recover some files from a failed hard drive from his Macbook Pro. This drive is only recognized using Ubuntu/Linux. I can go to his user folder open that but when I click on a folder inside it tells me I don't have permission. I've pretty much exhausted all the online help on this site but I'm a bit no, a big dummy when it comes to Unix etc.
This is the drive I'm trying to change. Can someone please spell out each command that needs to be done for this to happen?

```
/dev/sdb2 on /media/tuna/Wit's Macintosh HD type hfsplus (ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `gksudo nautilus` and enter your password, this will run file browser application with root access so it will have all permissions.

Comment: that worked ok. not sure why it wouldn't work yesterday!!